# Error when using R zeroinfl on negative binomial count data model

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, count-data, zero-inflation

I want to model number of plants in 12 different areas.
Each area is divided into smaller plots of equal size for all areas. The number of plots between areas vary (31 for the smallest area, 500 for the largest).
For each plot I have counted number of plants.
I also measure max canopy height for each plot.
I have a lot of plots with zero plants (a total of 2260 data points from a total of 2700), but also a few very high values (several hundered). Also, my data is overdispersed, for some areas, very overdispersed.
Because of this, I use a zero inflated negative binomial model:

PlantModel <-zeroinfl(Count ~ Area*CanopyHeight, data = datCount, dist = negbin)

When I run this, I get an error message:
In value[3L] :
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.72546e-38FALSE

I noted that others also have had similar problems and have tried to find ways to fix my data, but most of the problems seem to be because of a complicated model or too small datasets, which I do not have.
One thing that worked was to put the 12 Areas into broader categories, i.e 4 AreaTypes. This computes. However, I am really interested in each area and differences between them.

(As a sidenote: PlantModel <- glm.nb(Count ~ Area*CanopyHeight, data = datCount, link = "log") works fine)

Does someone have an idea what I could do to make the model run?
I am not a statistician, so please keep explanations as simple as possible.

Comment: My guess is that there are areas where a zero inflation model with regressor CanopyHeight can not be fitted, e.g. because all Count responses in that area are zero.